# Add new CRUD in the example "Play Java Ebean Example"

Tags: playframework, crud

I am new on Play Framework. I am trying to add new views on the example ("[Play Java Ebean Example](https://example.lightbend.com/v1/download/play-java-ebean-example)") from Play. I added new files for a CRUD for users but I can't edit, update or add a new user. The delete option is working fine as the list view of users.

play-java-ebean-example

This is an example Play application that uses Java, and communicates with an in memory database using EBean.

The Github location for this project is:

https://github.com/playframework/play-java-ebean-example

Play

Play documentation is here:

https://playframework.com/documentation/latest/Home

EBean

EBean is a Java ORM library that uses SQL:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/JavaEbean

and the documentation can be found here:

https://ebean-orm.github.io/

---

```
package controllers;

import models.Customer;
import models.CustomerUser;
import play.data.Form;
import play.data.FormFactory;
import play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecutionContext;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.mvc.Results;
import repository.CompanyRepository;

import repository.CustomerRepository;
import repository.CustomerUserRepository;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

/**
 * Manage a database of computers
 */
public class UserController extends Controller {

    private final CustomerUserRepository userRepository;
    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    //private final CompanyRepository companyRepository;
    private final FormFactory formFactory;
    private final HttpExecutionContext httpExecutionContext;

    @Inject
    public UserController(FormFactory formFactory,
                          CustomerUserRepository userRepository,

                          CustomerRepository customerRepository,
                          HttpExecutionContext httpExecutionContext) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.formFactory = formFactory;

        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
        this.httpExecutionContext = httpExecutionContext;
    }

    /**
     * This result directly redirect to application home.
     */
    private Result GO_HOME = Results.redirect(
            routes.UserController.list(0, "name", "asc", "")
    );

    /**
     * Handle default path requests, redirect to computers list
     */
    public Result index() {
        return GO_HOME;
    }

    /**
     * Display the paginated list of computers.
     *
     * @param page   Current page number (starts from 0)
     * @param sortBy Column to be sorted
     * @param order  Sort order (either asc or desc)
     * @param filter Filter applied on computer names
     */
    public CompletionStage<Result> list(int page, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
        // Run a db operation in another thread (using DatabaseExecutionContext)
        return userRepository.page(page, 10, sortBy, order, filter).thenApplyAsync(list -> {
            // This is the HTTP rendering thread context
            return ok(views.html.listuser.render(list, sortBy, order, filter));
        }, httpExecutionContext.current());
    }

    /**
     * Display the 'edit form' of a existing Computer.
     *
     * @param id Id of the computer to edit
     */
    public CompletionStage<Result> edit(Long id) {

        // Run a db operation in another thread (using DatabaseExecutionContext)
        CompletionStage<Map<String, String>> customersFuture = customerRepository.options();

        // Run the lookup also in another thread, then combine the results:
        return userRepository.lookup(id).thenCombineAsync(customersFuture, (userCustomerOptional, customers) -> {
            // This is the HTTP rendering thread context
            CustomerUser c = userCustomerOptional.get();
            Form<CustomerUser> userForm = formFactory.form(CustomerUser.class).fill(c);
            return ok(views.html.editFormUser.render(id, userForm, customers));
        }, httpExecutionContext.current());
    }

    /**
     * Handle the 'edit form' submission
     *
     * @param id Id of the user to edit
     */
    public CompletionStage<Result> update(Long id) throws PersistenceException {
        Form<CustomerUser> userForm = formFactory.form(CustomerUser.class).bindFromRequest();
        if (userForm.hasErrors()) {
            // Run companies db operation and then render the failure case
            return customerRepository.options().thenApplyAsync(customers -> {
                // This is the HTTP rendering thread context
                return badRequest(views.html.editFormUser.render(id, userForm, customers));
            }, httpExecutionContext.current());
        } else {
            CustomerUser newUser = userForm.get();
            // Run update operation and then flash and then redirect
            return userRepository.update(id, newUser).thenApplyAsync(data -> {
                // This is the HTTP rendering thread context
                flash("success", "Data - " + newUser.name + " has been updated");
                return GO_HOME;
            }, httpExecutionContext.current());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the 'new computer form'.
     */
    public CompletionStage<Result> create() {
        Form<CustomerUser> userForm = formFactory.form(CustomerUser.class);
        // Run companies db operation and then render the form

        return customerRepository.options().thenApplyAsync((Map<String, String> customers) -> {
            // This is the HTTP rendering thread context
            return ok(views.html.createFormUser.render(userForm, customers));
        }, httpExecutionContext.current());
    }

    /**
     * Handle the 'new computer form' submission
     */
    public CompletionStage<Result> save() {
        Form<CustomerUser> userForm = formFactory.form(CustomerUser.class).bindFromRequest();
        if (userForm.hasErrors()) {
            // Run companies db operation and then render the form


            return customerRepository.options().thenApplyAsync(customers -> {
                // This is the HTTP rendering thread context
                return badRequest(views.html.createFormUser.render(userForm, customers));
            }, httpExecutionContext.current());
        }

        CustomerUser cust = userForm.get();
        // Run insert db operation, then redirect
        return userRepository.insert(cust).thenApplyAsync(data -> {
            // This is the HTTP rendering thread context
            flash("success", "Data - " + cust.name + " has been created");
            return GO_HOME;
        }, httpExecutionContext.current());
    }

    /**
     * Handle computer deletion
     */
    //it works!!!
    public CompletionStage<Result> delete(Long id) {
        // Run delete db operation, then redirect
        return userRepository.delete(id).thenApplyAsync(v -> {
            // This is the HTTP rendering thread context
            flash("success", "User has been deleted");
            return GO_HOME;
        }, httpExecutionContext.current());
    }

}
```

---

```
package models;

import play.data.format.Formats;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Computer entity managed by Ebean
 */

@Entity
public class CustomerUser extends BaseModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String email;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String password;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String typeid;

    @ManyToOne
    public Customer customer;

}
```

---

```
package repository;

import io.ebean.Ebean;
import io.ebean.EbeanServer;
import io.ebean.PagedList;
import io.ebean.Transaction;
import models.CustomerUser;
import play.db.ebean.EbeanConfig;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

import static java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.supplyAsync;

/**
 * A repository that executes database operations in a different
 * execution context.
 */
public class CustomerUserRepository {

    private final EbeanServer ebeanServer;
    private final DatabaseExecutionContext executionContext;

    @Inject
    public CustomerUserRepository(EbeanConfig ebeanConfig, DatabaseExecutionContext executionContext) {
        this.ebeanServer = Ebean.getServer(ebeanConfig.defaultServer());
        this.executionContext = executionContext;
    }

    /**
     * Return a paged list of computer
     *
     * @param page     Page to display
     * @param pageSize Number of computers per page
     * @param sortBy   CustomerUser property used for sorting
     * @param order    Sort order (either or asc or desc)
     * @param filter   Filter applied on the name column
     */
    public CompletionStage<PagedList<CustomerUser>> page(int page, int pageSize, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
        return supplyAsync(() -> {
            return ebeanServer.find(CustomerUser.class).where()
                    .ilike("name", "%" + filter + "%")
                    .orderBy(sortBy + " " + order)
                    .fetch("customer")
                    .setFirstRow(page * pageSize)
                    .setMaxRows(pageSize)
                    .findPagedList();
        } , executionContext);
    }

    public CompletionStage<Optional<CustomerUser>> lookup(Long id) {
        return supplyAsync(() -> {
            return Optional.ofNullable(ebeanServer.find(CustomerUser.class).setId(id).findUnique());
        }, executionContext);
    }

    public CompletionStage<Optional<Long>> update(Long id, CustomerUser newUserData) {
        return supplyAsync(() -> {
            Transaction txn = ebeanServer.beginTransaction();
            Optional<Long> value = Optional.empty();
            try {
                CustomerUser savedUserCustomer = ebeanServer.find(CustomerUser.class).setId(id).findUnique();
                if (savedUserCustomer != null) {
                    savedUserCustomer.customer = newUserData.customer;
                    savedUserCustomer.typeid = newUserData.typeid;
                    savedUserCustomer.password = newUserData.password;
                    savedUserCustomer.email = newUserData.email;
                    savedUserCustomer.name = newUserData.name;

                    savedUserCustomer.update();
                    txn.commit();
                    value = Optional.of(id);
                }
            } finally {
                txn.end();
            }
            return value;
        }, executionContext);
    }

    public CompletionStage<Optional<Long>>  delete(Long id) {
        return supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                final Optional<CustomerUser> userCustomerOptional = Optional.ofNullable(ebeanServer.find(CustomerUser.class).setId(id).findUnique());
                userCustomerOptional.ifPresent(c -> c.delete());
                return userCustomerOptional.map(c -> c.id);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        }, executionContext);
    }

    public CompletionStage<Long> insert(CustomerUser customerUser) {
        return supplyAsync(() -> {
             customerUser.id = System.currentTimeMillis(); // not ideal, but it works
             ebeanServer.insert(customerUser);
             return customerUser.id;
        }, executionContext);
    }
}
```

---

```
@(id: Long, userForm: Form[CustomerUser], customers: Map[String, String])

@import helper._

@main {

<h1>Edit user</h1>

@form(routes.UserController.update(id)) {

<fieldset>
    @CSRF.formField
    @inputText(userForm("name"), '_label -> "User name", '_help -> "")
    @inputText(userForm("email"), '_label -> "E-mail", '_help -> "")
    @inputText(userForm("typeid"), '_label -> "Type Id", '_help -> "")

    @select(
    userForm("customer.id"),
    options(customers),
    '_label -> "Customer", '_default -> "-- Choose a customer --",
    '_showConstraints -> false
    )

</fieldset>

<div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" value="Save this user" class="btn primary"> or
    <a href="@routes.UserController.list()" class="btn">Cancel</a>
</div>

}

@form(routes.UserController.delete(id), 'class -> "topRight") {
@CSRF.formField
<input type="submit" value="Delete this user" class="btn danger">
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. It is required the password and I didn't put in my form. Now it is working perfect. The debug of IntelliJ helped me a lot. See you guys.